# What should 1 add to my CSS file to deacivate the default Chrome's CSS?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I want to deactivate the Chrome's default CSS like the input field background-color and all other stuff but i dont know how. Someone can explain me what i should do ? I should add some piece of code to my CSS file i guess.

To be more specific one of my problems is that i want to make an input text field with black background with background opacity of 0.5 and with white text color. So i made it and it work on IE or Mozilla but doesn't work on Chrome.

So all i want is to make my website's css to look same on Chrome as on Mozilla or IE.

Comment: You want to look for a "CSS reset" stylesheet. But native browser stylesheets vary a little over time, and there's no built-in way to explicitly disable all of them.

Comment: Override it to what you want it to be?

Comment: yes i want to override it. For most of them the "!important" doesnt work.

Comment: Did you try using a deeper css level? `.someClass .someOther .another { }`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use it on the radio or checkbox inputs any time as they can end up looking like an unuseful skinny rectangle.

```
input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="submit"]):not([type="button"]):not([type="file"]), 
select, 
textarea {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
       -moz-appearance:none;
            appearance:none;
}
```